# Raspberry-pi not detecting network when connected to a router via Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, setup

I have installed a fresh version of raspbian wheezy to my 8GB card.It is working fine when connected directly via hdmi.When i am connecting to the network via ethernet cable to a router,raspi is not detecting the network. The lights are also not turning on when connected to network.

I am having a 4GB card also which works fine on the same pi.So pretty sure not a hardware issue.I have flashed my 8GB card for a fresh installation.Is there any other setup i have to do??

Comment: How do the router distribute addresses? What is the output of `ifconfig` after you have connected?

Comment: Did you have raspbian on your 4GB card as well?

Comment: @user12321 yes..

Comment: So, do you say that when you use the other SD card, the Pi can connect to the router? Is the router works as DHCP? Are you setting the IP manually? Is there a chance of IP conflict?

Comment: no I'm not setting up IP mannually..

Comment: try to disable wifi connection first, use ip scanner to scan ip of raspberry. when wifi "on/enable" sometimes raspberry ip wont appear