# nmcli not detecting any network on R Pi 3 (controlled via SSH Ethernet)

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch, wireless, networkmanager

**SETUP:**
I plugged my laptop (Ubuntu 14) to my RPi 3 (Raspbian Stretch) via `ssh` over an Ethernet cable.

**PROBLEM:**

Doing **`nmcli dev wifi` on the laptop gives me a whole bunch of networks**. Typing **the same command on the R Pi gives me no network at all**. I have tried `ifconfig`, all the interfaces (`eth0`, `lo`, `wlan1`) appear as expected.

**ATTEMPTS:**

I tried :

- Edimax dongle (named `wlan0`): no network detected by that interface either.
- `systemctl restart network-manager`
- restart the interfaces (`ifconfig wlan1 down`)

to no avail.

Curiously, `iwlist wlan0 scan`  does return all the networks I am after.

**GOAL:**

My goal is to `nmcli dev wifi connect` to my network (I don't want to use `wpa_supplicant`)

**How to solve this please?**

I think it might be related to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22624/raspberry-pi-not-detecting-network-when-connected-to-a-router-via-ethernet-cable) (unsanswered) question.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73816/77005  It seems that getting network manager to run properly on Raspbian needs some additional work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @oh.dae.su. I followed the steps from this answer... but nmcli on the Rpi still doesn't detect anything. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Too bad. I didn't try the suggestions myself as I am happy with using wpa_supplicant. Unfortunately I don't have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Neither *Network Manager* (used by nmcli) nor old style networking with `ifupdown` is supported out of the box by Raspbian. For network connections it uses `dhcpcd` by default. You should look at `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` for default settings and have a look at `man dhcpcd` for using it.

I do not understand why you can use the command `nmcli` on the RasPi. On a default installation just from an image this command is not available. Do you not using a default installation?

To use it you have to install *Network Manager* and deinstall *dhcpcd*. Follow the link *@oh.dae.su* has suggested in his comment. But I'm not sure if this really completely fit into the hole environment of Raspbian.

For a general overview which three network management systems are available on Raspbian you can look at [How to correctly restart wpa_supplicant debug with networkd-systemd?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89729/79866). Network Manager isn't part of it. If you install it, it is the forth networking system. It doesn't make it simpler.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. When saying that " For network connections it uses dhcpcd by default." , "it" refers to Raspbian?
I think I might have apt-getted nmcli.

Comment: Also, I followed the steps referred to by @oh.dae.su, but this hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: @hartmut I have updated the answer with the last paragraph. I prefer systemd-networkd because it is the background of all services. So I cannot help you much with Network Manager. If possible I would suggest to use default dhcpcd. It is best integrated and there are great experience about it on this site. Or you use systemd-networkd because I believe it's the coming system in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (2023), Raspberry Pi OS (former Raspbian) comes with NetworkManager support, but it is disabled by default. To enable, run those commands:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager network-manager-gnome

# This command will enable NetworkManager, without needing to jump through GUI:
sudo raspi-config nonint do_netconf 2
sudo reboot
```

After reboot (for GUI), NetworkManager will be used.

And `nmcli` will work as expected, e.g. `nmcli dev wifi` will scan and list all visible WiFi APs.